# What does it mean if the line number in JS stacktrace is beyond the end of the file?

Tags: node.js, stack-trace

I have some code that is currently erroring out with the following stacktrace:

```
TypeError: Invalid attempt to destructure non-iterable instance
        at /Users/danrumney/WebstormProjects/ohana/app/auth-middleware.js:1934:585
        at _callee2$ (/Users/danrumney/WebstormProjects/ohana/app/auth-middleware.js:103:18)
```

The file `auth-middleware` is only 208 lines long, so how should I interpret `auth-middleware.js:1934:585`?

I'm not using any transpilers here. I am running this code as part of a unit test with Jest, but I don't imagine that's responsible for the weird line number.

As far as I know, Jest does not do any minification either.

I am using `async` and `await`. I'm using node 10.3

Comment: Does Jest minify anything whenever it runs?  I'd imagine *some* kind of bundling occurs.

Comment: Jest does not minify. FWIW, the second line in the stacktrace *is* a valid line, albeit a function signature.

Comment: I've added a few more details

Comment: Are there any *.js.map* files you could reference for that instance of the code? Maybe an incorrect source-map?